# Unable to create SQL Server database from Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a SQL Server database from Visual Studio Database Explorer. When I right click on Data Connections, the Create New SQL Server Database option remains grayed out.
[image: Disabled option to create new SQL Server Database]
I have VS Express 2012 and SQL Server Express 2012 installed in  my system. SQL Server instance is up and running.
Do I need to configure anything, so that Visual Studio recognizes the installed SQL Server instance?

Comment: I think you first need a connection before you can create a SQL Server database. Check this out: http://forums.asp.net/t/936009.aspx?+create+new+sql+server+database+command+is+disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to make a connection to the SQL Server before you can create a database.

Click the Add Connection option and connect to your SQL Server instance, then the option will become available on your connected Server.